# po [NSThread currentThread]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsthread

When I do po [NSThread currentThread], I got

{name = (null), num = 4}

When I look to the left I see:
[image]

Looks like it's Thread number 6, not 4. Also what properties do we need to call to get that thread numbers anyway?

[NSThread currentThread].number? Doesn't exist though.

Comment: I found `(lldb) thread info` more useful. You could use the `tid` to connect output from Console.app / NSLog back to the thread.
`thread #9: tid = 0x2e77, 0x0000000105293c9c`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thread numbers are meaningless, pretty much.

The thread instance, though, is a singleton per thread.   You could use the NSThread's address, by coincidence.   Better, still, would be to dip down to the mach_* API and grab the thread ID from that API.

`[NSThread currentThread]` is about as unique of a number as you'll get.  If the thread terminates and then a new thread is created, you might see the same address vended.  The mach APIs will vend something just about as unique, really.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you need per-thread data, I think what you want is either `-[NSThread threadDictionary]`, or (at a lower level) `pthread_getspecific()`/`pthread_setspecific()`.

Comment: Yup -- that'd be the way to go if you want per-thread data.  If you are trying to uniquely identify a thread, I might recommend generating a UUID and sticking it in the thread's dictionary.  That way, when a thread is exited and a new thread created, there is no risk of collision.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5:
It's a private variable, but accessible directly using keypath:

```
Thread.current.value(forKeyPath: "private.seqNum")!
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's the answer I posted to [NSThread number on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558411/nsthread-number-on-ios/15558934):

---

```
@implementation NSThread (ThreadGetIndex)

-(NSInteger)getThreadNum
{
    NSString * description = [ self description ] ;
    NSArray * keyValuePairs = [ description componentsSeparatedByString:@"," ] ;
    for( NSString * keyValuePair in keyValuePairs )
    {
        NSArray * components = [ keyValuePair componentsSeparatedByString:@"=" ] ;
        NSString * key = components[0] ;
        key = [ key stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[ NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet ] ] ;
        if ( [ key isEqualToString:@"number" ] || [ key isEqualToString:@"num" ] )
        {
            return [ components[1] integerValue ] ;
        }
    }
    @throw @"couldn't get thread num";
    return -1 ;
}

@end
```

Comment: WARNING: It seems in iOS8 "num" has become "number" (and "number" and "name" have swapped orders... though the above code is fine for that)

Comment: Useless answer, this method is only parsing the [NSThread description] and extracting the "number" value, the @Jim Thio question is completely different

Comment: @DaveOwens Thanks, I changed the snippet