# How to get NSThread num?

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging

I am looking for a simple way to get just the integer number for the current thread. For context I am using this as part of our global logging messages and don't need all the excessively verbose text that results from the just printing out the currentThread object.

Code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
```

Result:

```
<NSThread: 0x10a81e160>{name = (null), num = 1}
```

How do I easily just get the value of "num"?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558411/nsthread-number-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can not get 'num' value directly, because it is a private variable.
Another workaround is to parse description value.