# How to reveal private struct layout in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa

The question starts with my problem in getting a thread id.

I get answer in another answer [NSThread number on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558411/nsthread-number-on-ios/15559143#15559143).

By using KVC,we can get a thread id with

```
[[NSThread currentThread] valueForKeyPath:@"private.seqNum"]
```

My confusion is how to find out a object's internal ivar and even a private struct layout in this internal ivar.

Comment: If it's really a struct and not an Obj-C class, then there is little you can do.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use the *Objective-C Runtime* and related stuff such as `class_copyIvarList`. Look it up in the manual, what you want will probably be in that section.

Comment: Yes but OP mentions *object's internal ivar* so I assume it is object, which internally is a struct afaik anyhow.

Comment: Actually,I use Objective-C Runtime to get a ivar named '_private',then i can't do anymore to find out what's in '_private'. @skaak