# meaning of the returned value of [NSThread currentThread]

Tags: ios, debugging, nsthread

Could anyone please explain the meaning of the returned value of [NSThread currentThread]?

NSLog

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
```

Result

```
<NSThread: 0x1e04ed60>{name = (null), num = 5}
```

What are the following?

> 1. "NSThread: 0x1e04ed60"
> 2. name = (null)
> 3. num = 5

num = 5 doesn't have anything to do with the Thread number listed in the Xcode (which it shows Thread 9 for this instance, since I'm running multiple threads with NSOperationQueue)

the explanation from apple doc is pretty useless, 
Return Value
A thread object representing the current thread of execution.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is the memory address. The second is the thread name. You can set the name of a thread. The third number can be explained in these posts:

See:

[po [NSThread currentThread]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473258/po-nsthread-currentthread)

and

[NSThread number on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558411/nsthread-number-on-ios)